# Using jaxb converter tool xjc

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xjc

Is `xjc` from the command line (having `JAVA_HOME\bin` in your `PATH`) running `com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver`?
I.e.
Is running the class `com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver` the same as running `xjc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xjc.bat or xjc.sh just call -jar jaxb-xjc.jar.

I have jaxb-ri-20071219/lib/jaxb-xjc.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF:

> Main-Class: com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCFacade

From the [XJCFacade's source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons/jaxb-xjc/2.1.10.1/com/sun/tools/xjc/XJCFacade.java#XJCFacade):

> A shabby driver to invoke XJC1 or XJC2 depending on the command line
>   switch.

It then tries to call `com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver`.

But it could have changed in newer versions.
You can recheck MANIFEST.MF anyway.

Comment: `xjc.bat`? But in my installation I see `xjc.exe`. I am using `Windows`

Comment: Well, I have jdk1.6.0_24\bin\xjc.exe. Text search over this file for `com.sun.tools` gives only com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.Driver. See http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/com/sun/tools/internal/xjc/Driver.java#Driver